# I need to check a checkbox based on dataset result of 1 or 0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, vb.net-2010

I am trying to check my checkbox based on the result of a dataset. Memory_Error is the column in the database. I am inserting either a 1 or 0 as a string when the data is saved. I have looked and looked and looked for examples on how to do this and none seem to get the job done. I'm not getting any errors, I just end up with an unchecked checkbox when it should be checked. Thank you in advance for any assistance. My Apologies if I have not been concise with my explanation.

Here is my vb.net code.

```
 Dim dap2 As New SqlDataAdapter("Select ID, Store, Status, Reason, Detail, Detail_1, Detail_2,  Detail_3, Information, Memory_Error, Detail_4 FROM PollDetail where Poll_Date = '" & pollDate & "'", conn)
    conn.Open()
    Dim ds2 As New DataSet
    dap2.Fill(ds2, "PollDet")

    gvEmailRes2.DataSource = ds2

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To gvEmailRes2.Rows.Count - 1

        '-------------ckbMemErr-----------------------------------------------------------------/////
        If ds2.Tables("PollDet").Rows(i).Item(9) = "1" Then
            Dim row2Fill As GridViewRow = gvEmailRes2.Rows(i)
            Dim cbMemErr As CheckBox = DirectCast(row2Fill.FindControl("ckbMemErr"), CheckBox)
            cbMemErr.Checked = True

        ElseIf ds2.Tables("PollDet").Rows(i).Item(9) = "0" Then
            Dim row2Fill As GridViewRow = gvEmailRes2.Rows(i)
            Dim cbMemErr As CheckBox = DirectCast(row2Fill.FindControl("ckbMemErr"), CheckBox)
            cbMemErr.Checked = False

        End If
 Next

    gvEmailRes2.DataBind()
    conn.Close()
    dap2.Dispose()
```

And here is the ASP.NET

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Memory Error" SortExpression="Memory_Error" ItemStyle-    VerticalAlign="Top">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <br />
  <asp:CheckBox ID="ckbMemErr" runat="server" Text="Memory Error" Font-Size="11px" />
 </ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I believe calling `gvEmailRes2.DataBind()` would have override whatever your for..loop had done. Quit using loop and go for `gvEmailRes2.RowDataBound` event or put your for..loop logic after the `gvEmailRes2.DataBind()` line

Comment: Alright codingbiz!! I put the for loop after the bind and presto, it worked. Kudos my friend! And thank you too Andrea.

Comment: How do I give you a check or credit for giving me the correct answer codingbiz?

Answer (score 1):

When filling your grid remove the `for` cicle you posted. Instead put the same logic in the `RowDataBound` event:

step 1 - Load data

```
Dim dap2 As New SqlDataAdapter("Select ID, Store, Status, Reason, Detail, Detail_1, Detail_2,  Detail_3, Information, Memory_Error, Detail_4 FROM PollDetail where Poll_Date = '" & pollDate & "'", conn)
conn.Open()
Dim ds2 As New DataSet
dap2.Fill(ds2, "PollDet")
gvEmailRes2.DataSource = ds2
gvEmailRes2.DataBind()
conn.Close()
dap2.Dispose()
```

step 2 - setting checkboxes

```
Private Sub gvEmailRes2_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvEmailRes2.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim chk As Checkbox = CType(e.Row.FindControl("ckbMemErr"), Checkbox)
        Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)

        If Not chk Is Nothing and Not drv Is Nothing Then
            Dim err As Integer = 0
            If drv.Item("Memory_Error") <> "" and not IsDbNull(drv.Item("Memory_Error"))  Then
                err = CInt(drv.Item("Memory_Error"))
            End If
            If err = 1 Then
                chk.checked = True
            Else
                chk.checked = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Andrea. I tried the above code and got an error stating, "Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid." on the Dim err As Integer = CInt(drv.Item("Memory_Error")). It's not finding a value in chk.

Comment: Maybe you have some rows in your table with NULL value in column Memory_Error? Anyway before the assignment you can check if the value from the database is "": `drv.Item("Memory_Error")`

Comment: Edited the answer adding a test to avoid problems with NULL and empty string values: `If drv.Item("Memory_Error") <> "" and not IsDbNull(drv.Item("Memory_Error")) Then ...`